# Creating a feature for Better Answers to Bad Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers

## The problem I'm trying to address in a Feature

a lot of Questions on SO are bad as defined by the help center page which in itself is very informative. However I think as a new user, having concrete examples of these bad questions readily available would be helpful. Obviously If I suggested that every bad question be thoroughly analyzed and put into some sort of "Bad Question Example Page" Then the moderators would be up all night. The Mods and other high rep users do an austounding job of cleaning up SO and for that I respect them greatly. However that is not (exactly) what I'm suggesting.

## My Idea

Is to ease their burden. I see alot of new questions that obviously need cleaning but they haven't been because there are just too many bad questions. So what if, whenever someone asks a terrible question, instead of mods taking their important time to review and delete it, what If lower rep users and non-moderators could post a type of answer I will call a "Why this question is bad" Answer. Think of it like explaining a downvote, only, it's potentially a little longer/more informative for the OP and others, its not required, it potentially earns the answerer rep, and it immediately sorts the question into a "don't do this" example pile for continued value to SO. My Idea is to have this specific type of answer as a button near the downvote arrow for the question. This allows the answerer of a lower rep range (maybe 50 or 100 or something I'm open to suggestions) To post an answer as to why this question is bad. Then after a certain amount of Review by higher rep users or moderators, this "Answer" can be accepted by them (and not the asker). Maybe Instead of Review the answer gets "accepted" by the system after a certain amount of upvote criteria or something.

## Ok? but whats the point?

Point is that this might allow some of the janitorial duties of SO to be passed along to lower rep users without simply enabling people to delete, close and edit questions on a whim. The point of this is to help new users see concretely what is being asked of them and to ease the burden of mods and other fantastic reviewers. I also think this might be a good way for new users to gain rep as sometimes they (me) lack the expertise to answer questions as good as someone who's been on SO for awhile (not always true but its true about me). This would enable low rep users to clean up stack overflow and gain "trust" because of it. I think the help page and meta are great sources of what to do but as a new user I find that a concrete example helps me a lot. Obviously this won't prevent all the terrible questions but at the very least we might be able to get some value out of the people that consistently ask terrible questions (before the system gives them a question ban of course).

## Notes/Discussion to you

This might be viable or might not be viable and thats why I wanted to see what you guys thought about this as a potential answering feature, What do you think? Should low rep users have the oppurtunity to gain rep by cleaning up SO this way? Should it be done differently or not at all? I leave it to you!

This is strongly related to "Give first time askers real examples of bad questions before posting?" However I beelive this not to be a duplicate because while they address the same underlying issue, they do it in radically different ways with different consequences.

## Edits/Updates based on good feedback

I've read a good answer to this and I believe parts of my question were unclear/lacked understanding on my part. Addressing the "noise concerns" this is meant to reduce noise by taking these questions out of the system and putting them in a seperate pile where someone would have to actively search for "Bad Questions". It would NOT show up under the regular tags and search results. The Ideal workflow for this process is, OP posts a bad question, OP gets a chance to correct if, if OP does not and someone wants to post an Answer saying why this question is bad then they can do so. Then if a Answer such as this were to be posted on the question, that question is not "closed" until the Answer was reviewed or hit some sort of criteria (upvotes maybe?). It does not immediately close the question. If the question was good and someone posted this type of answer, then the idea is that this type of answer would be removed. This type of answer would only be accepted after some criteria, review or upvotes or something. I have noted the concern that this would "increase work" for reviewers and thats why I was open to suggestions about this being not review acceptance based but possibly upvote acceptance based.

## Why I think its not a duplicate

I beleive this question not to be a duplicate of "Should one advise on off-topic questions?". Because I ask about the "How" rather than the "If we should". This is more about a suggestion for how you can advise on off topic questions with regards to a specific feature request rather than an overarching discussion on how we should advise on off topic questions. I believe this question is more specific in scope and talks more about "how" than "why". I'm open to all interpretations however and I Do think the questions are strongly linked.

I appreciate the feedback immensely. The consensus seems to be, this would not be viable and its being covered already. I've seen another good answer that suggests much of this is done already and ignored where it being ignored is the root problem. I'd be interested to know why you feel stuff like the help page, comments ect is ignored and what ideas you might have to make something like this and/or the things we already have, unignorable or at least less likely to be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

Imho, it's a suboptimal idea because it would leave a lot of questions on the site that don't have answers and also can't be answered. This will drastically increase the noise ratio when searching for a problem. From a searching perspective, this would mean that you find a question that asks about the problem you are looking for, then you read the answer just to find out that it does not solve the actual problem but just describes how the question can be improved. This answer only helps the asker, but not anyone else who later stumbles over the question.

Also, allowing low-rep users to write those answers sounds also not very promising. Low-rep users are usually those who have the least knowledge how the site work and what is considered a good question. I also don't see how this would help clean-up SO.

What happens to the question when someone adds such an answer? Can it still be answered? Is it closed? What happens when someone leaves such an answer on a question that was OK? Then, how would this be cleaned up? What if op improves his question according to the feedback? Would this then require an additional review-queue were the improvement answers get deleted?

Introducing a new review queue to review answers does not seem to reduce the amount of work high-rep users have. Actually it will make more work. Reviewing an answer for accuracy takes way more time than to vote-to-close.

In total, this sounds like a lot of work time wasted, either in the new review queues or when writing such answers, for something that can already kind of be done with comments.

Side note: Mods are usually not involved in quality control. Most of the work is done by regular users who have enough reputation to do the job (most of the tasks don't require a very high rep).

Answer (score 5):

We have:

- **Comments**, where users regularly explain what's wrong with questions and request improvements from the author to help fix them, which are mostly ignored
- **Close and flag reasons** (including a free-text one), which are mostly ignored
- **Meta**, where one can request an extensive explanation of what's wrong with a question, or find plenty of existing examples and more general asking tips, which people regularly link to in comments, but such comments are mostly ignored
- **The Help Center**, where one can find more general asking tips, which people regularly link to in comments, but such comments, and the Help Center as a whole, are mostly ignored

(Ignored by the asker, that is)

What you're proposing sounds a lot like a combination of all of that, which I'm not convinced there's actually a need for.

I'd be all for a good proposal to make it easier to get rid of bad questions, but this sounds more focused on the part that most askers currently ignore (and this doesn't seem like it would do much to address them ignoring it).

As for the general idea of getting reputation for moderation tasks - there might be some value in that, but, as far as I've seen and can recall, Stack Overflow seems pretty opposed to that idea (except for the fact that [you can gain up to 1k from edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)).